# MATLAB default figure font sizes

Tags: matlab, default-value, font-size, matlab-figure

I've found that I can put `set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontSize',14)` in a startup.m file, which then changes the default font size of ticks, axes labels, and title of my figures. Is it possible to have a separate default font size for the title or axes labels?

Comment: Relevant note: I checked out `get(0,'Factory')` and `get(0,'default')` and didn't see anything related to figure font size other than the one mentioned above...

Comment: Last time I checked (Matlab2010b) there was no default for fontsizes besides DefaultAxesFontSize and DefaultTextFontSize. And I don't think they added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a separate default font size for titles and labels with the standard mechanisms. If you are willing to overload the labelling commands, then you can come pretty close. The easiest would be to modify `xlabel` to allow for a default font. You would need to add

```
if ~isempty(getappdata(ax, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
    set(h, 'FontSize', getappdata(ax, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
else
    if ~isempty(getappdata(get(ax, 'parent'), 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
        set(h, 'FontSize', getappdata(get(ax, 'parent'), 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
    elseif ~isempty(getappdata(0, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
        set(h, 'FontSize', getappdata(0, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
    end
end
```

immediately before

```
set(h, 'String', string, pvpairs{:});
```

If you don't want to modify a core file you can overload `xlabel`

```
function varargout = xlabel(varargin)
    ax = axescheck(varargin{:});
    if isempty(ax)
      ax = gca;
    end
    oldPath = pwd;
    cd([matlabroot, filesep, 'toolbox', filesep, 'matlab', filesep, 'graph2d']);
    xlabel = str2func('xlabel');
    cd(oldPath);

    oldFontsize = get(ax, 'FontSize');
    if ~isempty(getappdata(ax, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
        set(ax, 'FontSize', getappdata(ax, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
    else
            if ~isempty(getappdata(get(ax, 'parent'), 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
                set(ax, 'FontSize', getappdata(get(ax, 'parent'), 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
        elseif ~isempty(getappdata(0, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'))
                set(ax, 'FontSize', getappdata(0, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize'));
           end
    end
    varargout{1:nargout} = xlabel(varargin{:});
    set(ax, 'FontSize', oldFontsize);
    if ~nargout
        varargout = {};
    end
end
```

Either way, you can set the default font size with

```
setappdata(0, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize', 36)
```

or

```
setappdata(gcf, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize', 36)
```

or

```
setappdata(gca, 'DefaultAxesXLabelFontSize', 36)
```

Note that it uses `setappdata` and not `set`.